# Error: Directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden when deploying Laravel app using elastic beanstalk

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I tried to deploy a laravel application using elastic beanstalk. The configuration is that I set the EC2 instance (webserver) to be in the private subnet and an application load balancer for public exposure. The website is working fine when being accessed through the web browser, however, I could still see that my beanstalk status is "severe" and the EC2 instance is getting an "unhealthy" status as seen from the load balancer targets. I checked the logs from the elastic beanstalk dashboard and could see the error from the Nginx error.logs:

**directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden**

Is there anything else that I might be missing here? A config, or a setting?

Comment: Temporary try changing permission of `/var/www/html` to 755 then check if not work don't forget to revert back. Also make sure your php is running from browser.

Comment: thanks @aviboy2006. I didn't have the time to try the suggestion because the project was urgent. I had to come up with an alternative, therefore I deployed manually in the way I know using Apache. But my guess is there could be other dependencies that I'm missing in the server.

Comment: Has a long term solution been found for this?

Comment: @EvanLalo nah man. Since I needed to provision the website asap, I didn't have time to investigate on this further. Sorry bro